# Flower.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations

Tags: java

The compiler gives 2 warnings after running the following command:

```
javac Flower.java -Xlint:unchecked
```

First warning:

```
Flower.java:33: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
        updateComboBox((JComboBox<String>) formComponents.get("myComboBox"));
                                                             ^
  required: JComboBox<String>
  found:    Component
```

Second warning:

```
 Flower.java:36: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
                JComboBox<String> cmbProfCourseNo = (JComboBox<String>) formComponents.get("myComboBox");
                                                                                          ^
  required: JComboBox<String>
  found:    Component
```

I tried to make it generic as shown below, but no changes.

```
DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = (DefaultComboBoxModel<String>) comboBox.getModel();
```

Flower.java Full source code is :

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;


class Flower 
{   
    //declare the frame
    private JFrame frame;

    //declare HashMap
    private Map<String, Component> formComponents= new HashMap<String, Component>();

    //main method of the class 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Flower().init();
    }

    public void init() {
        frame = new JFrame("Flower");
        frame.setSize(650, 725);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        formComponents.put("myComboBox", new JComboBox<String>());
        formComponents.get("myComboBox").setBounds(125, 165, 200, 25);
        frame.add(formComponents.get("myComboBox"));
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //update comboBox
        updateComboBox((JComboBox<String>) formComponents.get("myComboBox"));

        //get comboBox
        JComboBox<String> cmbProfCourseNo = (JComboBox<String>) formComponents.get("myComboBox");
    }


    public void updateComboBox(JComboBox<String> comboBox) {        
        DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = (DefaultComboBoxModel<String>) comboBox.getModel();        
        model.addElement("Car");
        //set the model
        comboBox.setModel(model);
    }
}
```

My HashMap has to store JLabel, JTextField and other JComponents so I declared its type as Component (as Component is an upper class in Swing hierarchy).

Answer (score 2):

```
public void updateComboBox(JComboBox<String> comboBox) {
    //get the combo box model
    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = (DefaultComboBoxModel<String>) comboBox.getModel();

    model.addElement("Car");
    //set the model
    comboBox.setModel(model);
}
```

but those just warring, the compiler can deal with them...

Comment: Now I am getting following warning               `Flower.java:320: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
        updateComboBox((JComboBox<String>) (formComponents.get("myComboBox")));
                                                            ^
  required: JComboBox<String>
  found:    Component`

Comment: @BrainyPrb you didn't post this code... I need to more

Comment: `formComponents` is a HasMap which stores objects of type `Component`. So I am trying to type cast `Component` to `JComboBox`. Why is it not working ?

Comment: I have updated the question, re-posted the warnings and also the relevant code. Please consider.